# Move more views images to the left of the main product image

Tags: layout, catalog, product-images, magento-2.1.3

I would like to move the more views product images from bottom of the main product image to the left of the main product image, with all the existing functionality intact. 
It would be very nice if someone can guide me towards it.

Comment: please let me know if you have query.

Answer (score 4):

Just override **etc/view.xml** file of catalog module and do changes as per below,

**app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/etc/view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
         <!-- for product page thumbnail -->
         <var name="gallery">
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
         </var>
         <!-- for fullscreen thumbnail -->
         <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
         </var>
    </vars>
</view>
```